# Amazon RDS - Increase storage size did not increase IOPS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We started sending a lot of data to a recently deployed application yesterday, that quickly used all the IOPS burst of the RDS instance that got stucked to 30 IOPS (The application was created on elastic beanstalk with a Postgresql database and 10 GB SSD storage)

Following the documentation I increased the storage space to 50 GB in order to get more IOPS (150 I guess).  I did this 18 hours ago but the instance is still limited to 30 IOPS which create a very high latency on our application...

Any idea on how I can get this fixed?

Comment: which storage class are you using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the type of storage class you use, if you set it to apply immediately it should come into affect otherwise it will take affect in the next maintainance window.

[image: Aws Maintainance Downtime and when the change occurs]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it did in fact apply, I didn't see that RDS instances had CPU credits and that I had used all of them, I have upgraded the instance to a bigger class and everything is running smooth now.  I mark your answer as accepted as it still gave useful information :)